# Amazon Mobile Analytics for ionic Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework

I'm would like to know how to connect Amazon Mobile Analytics with my ionic application. There aren't any tutorials explaining how to use it with ionic so any help will be appreciated.

I followed the documentation provided by amazon / https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-mobile-analytics-js / but I only got it to work in the browser. It's not working when I'm testing it on mobile devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCMBFPXR2XWOF/Use-Amazon-Mobile-Analytics-with-your-JavaScript-enabled-apps) you can find a blog post describing how to use Amazon Mobile Analytics in Ionic apps.

If this is what you already did - do you get any error message when testing on a mobile device?

**EDIT**

It's important to whitelist all calls to *.amazonaws.com URLs so requests from the Amazon SDK wont get blocked!

Comment: No errors, nothing. I put some test alerts, but I don't get any off them after the code which should connect to the Amazon Mobile Analytics. I get them when running in the browser.

Comment: Did you whitelist the *.amazonaws.com calls? Also, did you activate the additional debug output by passing a logger when setting the options?

Comment: Can you give me hints. :)

Comment: I added them in the whitelist and it worked. Thanks :) You can edit your comment and add it as s preposition. It will help others :)

Comment: @nikitz Great! Please accept my answer if it worked for you.